# How to fetch POST in a class component using @auth0/auth0-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0

GET fetch will work, but when I attempt the POST fetch this is the error I'm seeing...

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

for this line...
const { getAccessTokenSilently } = this.props.auth0;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { IP } from '../constants/IP'
import { withAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

class AddATournament extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.myNewListOfAllTournamentsWithAuth()
    }

    state = {
        tournament_name: '',
        all_tournaments: [],
    }

    async myNewListOfAllTournamentsWithAuth() {
        const { getAccessTokenSilently } = this.props.auth0;
        const token = await getAccessTokenSilently({
          audience: `http://localhost:3000`,
          scope: 'read:tournaments',
        });

        fetch(`http://${IP}:3000/tournaments`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({
            all_tournaments: data
        }))
    } 
    
    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            tournament_name: e.target.value
        })
    }

    async newHandleSubmitToAddATournamentWithAuth (event) {
        const { getAccessTokenSilently } = this.props.auth0;
        const token = await getAccessTokenSilently({
        audience: `http://localhost:3000`,
        scope: 'create:tournaments',
        });

        fetch(`http://${IP}:3000/tournaments`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accepts': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({tournament_name: this.state.tournament_name,
            })
        })
    }

  render() {
   console.log("show me all tournaments", this.state.all_tournaments)

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h2> Add A New Tournament
                {
                    <form onSubmit={this.newHandleSubmitToAddATournamentWithAuth}>
                        <br></br><label>
                        Tournament Name: 
                        <input 
                            onChange={this.onChange} 
                            type='text' tournament_name='tournament_name' 
                            value={this.state.tournament_name} />
                        </label>
                        <input type='submit' value='submit' />
                    </form>
                }
            </h2>
     )
  }
}

export default withAuth0(AddATournament);
```

Not sure that the componentDidMount is necessary for the GET. But think the issue with the POST may have something to do with rendering? I know I can't include the newHandleSubmitToAddATournamentWithAuth in the didMount because it takes in an event param. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are not binding your functions to `this`. Methods defined in your Class do not have access to `this` unless you write them as arrow functions (like your `onChange`) or if you want to write them as functions, you need to bind them in constructor. Consider this solution:

```
constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      tournament_name: '',
      all_tournaments: [],
    }

    this.mymyNewListOfAllTournamentsWithAuth = this.mymyNewListOfAllTournamentsWithAuth.bind(this)
    this.newHandleSubmitToAddATournamentWithAuth = this.newHandleSubmitToAddATournamentWithAuth.bind(
      this
    )
  }
```

If you want to avoid this in the constructor, you can modify your functions like this:

`const myNewListOfAllTournamentsWithAuth = async () => {...`

`const newHandleSubmitToAddATournamentWithAuth = async (event) => {`

Arrow functions are automatically binded and have access to `this`